# Explosion/fire not showing up after bake in viewport or rendered

Tags: particles, physics, baking, smoke-simulation, fire

I was following an explosion tutorial for 2.82 on youtube and he did a bake and after that, the explosion showed up, but when I do it the domain changes sizes but the explosion does not show up, I have tried clearing my cache folder and restarting my computer and blender but nothing happens still.[image: my cache settings][image: my baked data][image: the bake not working]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/181499/bake-data-button-not-visible-in-fluid-options/181501#181501

Answer (score 0):

I was having this issue even after baking the data. And It finally started rendering after I baked the noise as well.

Comment: Please don't use the answers section (and Set the cache type from replay to final ; ) )

Comment: Sorry, first time hear :}