# 'Bake data' button not visible in fluid options

Tags: baking, fluid-simulation

(new to blender) i am trying to create a fluid sim in blender 2.83 but in my physics tab under domain there is no 'bake data' button in the options. It's there in all the tutorials i've watched but i dont seem to have it.

[image: physics tab for my domain cube]

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It's because the cache type is set by default to "Replay". Replay does not provide any caching at all; it's used for instant replay. If you want to bake data, you should change cache type to modular or final (for final baking all physics)

[image]

And don't forget, that you need to save file before any cache type of simulations.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the answer. Just to help people understand screenshots better, I would suggest applying the default theme temporarily while taking them. Thanks.

Answer (score 14):

By default the **Cache-Type** is set to **Replay** and interactively shows the simulations in *realtime*.
*(depending on your system that is)*
[image]
*marked red the defaults for the "Cache"-sub-Panel and the Type: Replay*

There are actually 2 ways for **baking**:

1. Changing the **Cache-Type** to **Modular**, makes a **Bake Data** button appear at the bottom of the **Settings**-*Panel*. That button bakes and caches the **Liquid** (if checked) and let's you afterwards bake the **Mesh** (with it's own button) as well if you so desire (even if Mesh is checked it won't be baked in one go).
   [image]
   *red marked, setting the type to "Modal"(1.) displays the Button (2.) for backing*
2. The **Cache-Type** set to **Final** on the other hand makes a **Bake All** button appear in the **Cache**-*Panel* and by pressing that one button, the **Liquid** and if also checked **Mesh** will be baked/cached in one fell swoop. You can also **Free All** *(If data is cached the button changes)* with that same button if needed.
   [image]
   *red marked, setting the type to "Final"(1.) displays the "Bake All" (2.) button*

Testing/building with "Replay" is the usual approach, thus it is default.
I tend to bake the Liquid and Mesh separately aka. "Modular", but once you are set and do not need to make more adjustments, you can use "Final" to safe yourself some clicking and scrolling.

Happy Blending